# I would like the listview item to display the data of the relevant item in new activity

Tags: android, listview, indexing

Currently, the code i have only displays the data (on a new activity when clicked) at index 0 of that list view - not the item i actually clicked. i would like to somehow change my code so it can display the data at index n (n being the item i clicked in list view):

**ResultsActivity.java**

```
final ArrayList<String> searchResults = getValuesFromJSON(jsonResult);

    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, searchResults);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    //list items become clickable and open the movie detail page which displays the movie data of the specific movie
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent newActivity = new Intent(ResultsActivity.this, MoviePage.class);
            newActivity.putStringArrayListExtra("movie data", searchResults);
            startActivity(newActivity);
        }
    });
}
```

**MoviePage.java**

```
 ArrayList<String> searchResults = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("movie data");

    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewfinal);
    t.setText(searchResults.get(9));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a onclick listener on your listview so you can listen for item click events.
Put this in your onCreate method in your activity:

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 

      @Override 
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
//you can move the textview to a class variable if you want
      TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewfinal);
        t.setText(searchResults.get(position));

      } 
    });
```

update: you'll want to pass the position to the next activity the same way your passing the searchResults to MoviePage so just do this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(ResultsActivity.this, MoviePage.class);
        newActivity.putStringArrayListExtra("movie data", searchResults);
         newActivity.putExtra("position",position);//pass the position to the next activity
        startActivity(newActivity);
    } 
});
```

now in MoviePage.java

```
ArrayList<String> searchResults = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("movie data");
 int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position",0);
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewfinal);
    t.setText(searchResults.get(position));
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. when i do 'position' in the other class it turns red.

Comment: updated to show the bits i added with the intention to pass json data between both activities and make the data display when each specific listview item is clicked

Comment: there is a red squiggle under this line of code: int position = getIntent().getStringExtra("position"); and the error reads 'int, incompatible types'

Comment: my fault, i updated the answer. Should be getIntent().getIntExtra("position",0);

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

**ResultsActivity.java**

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent newActivity = new Intent(ResultsActivity.this, MoviePage.class);
            newActivity.putExtra("movie data", searchResults.get(position));
            startActivity(newActivity);
        }
    });
```

**MoviePage.java**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

if (extras != null) {
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewfinal);
    t.setText(extras.getString("movie data"));
}
```